# Getting run time path of a file in Eclipse for an AutoIt script

Tags: eclipse, file-upload, runtime, autoit, absolute-path

I want to write an [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) script for a file upload in my automation code in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I am keeping my file to be uploaded in `Project/resources/my_file.txt`.

I have written FileUpload.au3 as:

```
 WinWait("File Upload","",10)
 ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
 Sleep(2000)
 ControlSetText("File Upload" , "", "Edit1",   "resources/my_file.txt")
 Sleep(2000)
 ControlClick("File Upload" , "","Button1");
```

If I compile the above file and create FileUpload.exe and call FileUpload.exe in my code, the problem is with the path of the file to be uploaded as that will differ system to system.

How do I get the absolute path of resources/my_file.txt and use that at runtime in my AutoIt script?

Comment: Hmm, you can try using the WorkingDir macro like so: @WorkingDir & 'resources/my_file.txt'.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove hi thanks for ur reply but i didn't get u properly....

Comment: @fresher What Mr. Hargrove is saying is that you should try to call `ControlSetText` with the `@WorkingDir` macro like so: `ControlSetText("File Upload" , "", "Edit1", @WorkingDir & "resources/my_file.txt")`.

Comment: Thank you @mrt you explained perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special array $CmdLine is initialized with the command line parameters passed in to your AutoIt script.  Note the scriptname is not classed as a parameter; get this information with @ScriptName instead.  A parameter that contains spaces must be surrounded by "double quotes".  Compiled scripts accept command line parameters in the same way.

$CmdLine[0] is number of parameters
$CmdLine[1] is param 1 (after the script name)
$CmdLine[2] is param 2 etc
...
$CmdLine[$CmdLine[0]] is one way to get the last parameter...

So if your script is run like this:

```
AutoIt3.exe myscript.au3 param1 "this is another param"
```

$CmdLine[0] equals... 2

$CmdLine[1] equals... param1

$CmdLine[2] equals... this is another param

@ScriptName equals... myscript.au3

In addition to $CmdLine there is a variable called $CmdLineRaw that contains the entire command line unsplit

Here is how it should be done in your case:

```
 WinWait("File Upload","",10)
 ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
 Sleep(2000)
 ControlSetText("File Upload" , "", "Edit1",   $CmdLineRaw)
 Sleep(2000)
 ControlClick("File Upload" , "","Button1");
```

Then you send a command line argument when you call compiled autoit

```
Run("FileUpload.exe resources/my_file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .It worked.Now I am able send the path of the file dynamically.